# Intellij and gradle dependency issue

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build, dependencies, runtime

Today I'm facing a true problem with a small project I started from scratch using Intellij, Java 8 and Gradle. I'm quite new to Gradle and learning a lot, but I'm currently blocked to what seems to be a straightforward issue:

I cut my project in several modules, like there is one main module and in it there are several ones, like this:

[Project overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeRaY.png)

It builds OK using gradle clean build :

```
13:54:26: Executing task 'build'...

:obd2-common:compileJava
:obd2-common:processResources NO-SOURCE
:obd2-common:classes
:obd2-common:jar
:obd2-bt:compileJava
:obd2-bt:processResources
:obd2-bt:classes
:obd2-bt:jar
:obd2-net:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:obd2-net:processResources NO-SOURCE
:obd2-net:classes UP-TO-DATE
:obd2-net:jar
:obd2-simulator:compileJava
:obd2-simulator:processResources
:obd2-simulator:classes
:obd2-simulator:jar
:obd2-polling:compileJava
:obd2-polling:processResources
:obd2-polling:classes
:obd2-polling:jar
:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:processResources NO-SOURCE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test NO-SOURCE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build
:obd2-bt:assemble
:obd2-bt:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:obd2-bt:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:obd2-bt:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:obd2-bt:test NO-SOURCE
:obd2-bt:check UP-TO-DATE
:obd2-bt:build
:obd2-common:assemble
:obd2-common:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:obd2-common:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:obd2-common:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:obd2-common:test NO-SOURCE
:obd2-common:check UP-TO-DATE
:obd2-common:build
:obd2-net:assemble
:obd2-net:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:obd2-net:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:obd2-net:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:obd2-net:test NO-SOURCE
:obd2-net:check UP-TO-DATE
:obd2-net:build
:obd2-polling:assemble
:obd2-polling:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:obd2-polling:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:obd2-polling:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:obd2-polling:test NO-SOURCE
:obd2-polling:check UP-TO-DATE
:obd2-polling:build
:obd2-simulator:assemble
:obd2-simulator:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:obd2-simulator:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:obd2-simulator:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:obd2-simulator:test NO-SOURCE
:obd2-simulator:check UP-TO-DATE
:obd2-simulator:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
13 actionable tasks: 13 executed
13:54:27: Task execution finished 'build'.
```

But for an unknown yet annoying reason, IntelliJ don't want to run a main within one of the modules. This class contains references to outer classes (from another submodule). IntelliJ in the code says it's ok, Gradle when building says it's ok, but when I try to run the code and IntelliJ builds, it fails.

Here are the different build.gradle:

1. The main module ("obd2"):

build.gradle:

```
plugins {

    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'tech.necko.obd2'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

task zip(type: Zip) {
    from configurations.runtime.allArtifacts.files
    from configurations.runtime
    into 'release'
}
```

2. obd2-polling

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'tech.necko.obd2'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.2'
    compile project(':obd2-common')
    compile project(':obd2-simulator')
    compile project(':obd2-bt')
    compile project(':obd2-net')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class' : 'tech.necko.obd2.Poller'
    }
}
```

3. obd2-simulator:

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'tech.necko.obd2'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':obd2-common')
    compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

4. obd2-bt

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'tech.necko.obd2'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile project(':obd2-common')
}
```

5. obd2-net

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'tech.necko.obd2'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

6. obd2-common

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'tech.necko.obd2'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

I don't know if it is a standard gradle feature but it cut each of my module in two sub-modules: main and test. I checked within intelliJ for the project properties and it reflects what's inside the build files...

Thank you !

Comment: Do you have "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle" option enabled in "Settings | Build... | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a lot, trying a lot of solutions, I found out I had to rebuild the entire project using IntelliJ's builder :

[Build in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7efi.png)